# How do I give a string object a custom method in Python?

Tags: python, string

Similar to ".format", I want to be able to automatically prefix the time before a string. I really have no idea to do it but I think it might look something like this.

```
>>print("Function __init__ at CLASS myClass running...".log())
```

Prints:

> > [myPrefix] Function **init** at CLASS myClass running...

I have no idea in the world of how I would do this.

Comment: You can't add methods to builtin types in Python.  You'd have to define your own subclass of `str` and use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't even monkey-patch attributes onto built-in types. This:

```
def log(self):
    print "logging "+self
str.log = log 

str("hello")

print "hello".log()
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 3, in <module>
    str.log = log 
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

The best way to do this is to just write a logging method, like so:

```
def log(s):
    print("my-prefix -- "+s)

log("hello")
```

The advantage of this is that, if at a later stage, you decide to not print your logging statements, but pipe them into a file, you only need to change the `log` function, not the many places you have the print statements, for example:

```
def log(s):
    with open("my_log.txt",w) as f:
        data = f.write("the time - " + s)

log("hello")
```

Now, all your logging statements go to the file, without having to change the actual logging call.